# Is it possible to create sections of code in Lua?

Tags: lua, brackets

Like in some languages, you can add brackets to specify code. Is there something which I can do in Lua to split sections of my code up similar to the example below?

```
{
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Sections of code for what purpose?

Comment: Do you mean as in the following .cpp file, for example: http://sourceforge.net/p/lua-icxx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/test/main.cpp? If so, then @Adam's answer is correct. However, scoping and finalization of objects is very different in Lua than it is in, say, C++, so whereas the example main.cpp given uses it in conjunction with RAII to automate some checks, in Lua that would not work. Why do you want this in Lua?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create a scope with `do ... end`

```
do
   -- Code
end
```